# Prevent indexing through enhanced ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-image-search

We are running a webshop for wholesale customers where all prices are hidden until you login.

We are using Google Analytics with enhanced ecommerce to track how the customers are using the site and the value of their orders.

Recently we saw that Google has started showing our prices (which are supposed to be secret) along the images in Image Search on mobile devices.

Are Google using our tracking data to feed their index of product data? And is there a way to prevent this from happening while keeping the tracking functionality including price data?

Comment: @DaImTo I couldn't find a single question about enhanced ecommerce on webapps, but many questions here on stack overflow. That's why I posted here.

Comment: If you want to post your code and describe what issues you are having with your code. Then by all means it should be here.

Comment: @DaImTo This is not a code issue, however I selected this community since Webapps doesn't have any similar questions but Stack overflow does. I hope that makes sense to you!

Comment: @DalmTo I guess what I am looking for is a way to prevent Google from indexing the product data through code. I am asking a way to solve the issue by coding.